# Is there any way to edit user uid, or create user with specific user uid?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

The collection names and doc name are depends on user input so while retrieving user data I don't the names of collection and doc and the only thing I can get from the current user is user uid.

Is there any way to edit user uid, or create user with specific user uid?

That way I can store collection and doc name in uid and seperate them later while retrieving user data.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way for you to change the UID of users that are generated with the built-in providers of Firebase Authentication.

The only way to determine the UID yourself is when you implement your own provider, as shown in the documentation on [custom authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/custom-auth) and [minting custom tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens).